# UART Send/Receive not working

Tags: python, serial, uart

I'm trying to get communication though UART with a freedom board working with Python3 on Raspberry 3 Jessie. This is my first attempt and I don't have any experience in that. The code of the freedom board is maintained by someone else, I have only control over the pi.

**Problem 1**: When I try to send something with `uart.write("Test".encode())` the whole program hangs on this line and doesn't respond anymore.

Here is a test I tried:

```
uart = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, timeout=1)
uart.write("Test".encode())
```

**Problem 2:** The code doesn't seem to be able to received data.: When I try do run a program to simply receive and print everything I get, it doesn't seem to receive anything at all.

```
uart = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, timeout=1)
while True:
    rec = uart.read(2)
    print("Rec: {0}".format(rec))
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

I get the following output:

```
Rec: b''
Rec: b''
Rec: b''
Rec: b''
```

I assume that read() runs into a timeout after 1 second because it didn't receive anything and then just prints an empty binary-string, is that correct?

Some questions:

- According to [elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection](http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection) I have to set "Serial" setting in raspi_config to disabled in order to use it for this purpose. Is that correct?
- What can I do, when write() doesn't return properly and hangs the whole code?
- is `/dev/ttyAMA0` the right port? I have connected the GPIO pins 14 and 15 for TX and RX. After `uart = serial.Serial(......)` I can test the connection with `uart.isOpen()` and it returns true. Because of this I think it is correct. Right?
- I don't receive anything at all. What can I do?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I haven't waded through the whole question but unless you are trying to write to Bluetooth See [How-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697)

Comment: Ditto.  You should make it plain if you have followed the necessary steps to enable `ttyAMA0` as the breakout UART since by default on the Pi 3 it is not.  If you haven't done that, then you should...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used the wrong port for the serial communication.
I tried to establish a connection with `/dev/ttyAMA0` and that seemed to work. At least I got an open connection.

But as mentioned in [Milliways Answer on another question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3/45571#45571) that port seems to be used for Bluetooth communication and isn't connected to the gpio pins 14 and 15.

I tried to use `/dev/serial0`, but I got the following error on opening the connection:

> serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port /dev/serial0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/serial0'

To use that port I had to enable uart as mentioned by [Milliways Answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3/45571#45571).

> For some bizarre reason the default for Pi3 using the latest 4.4.9 kernel is to DISABLE UART. The enable it you need to change `enable_uart=1` in `/boot/config.txt`.

After that I was able to open the right port and `uart.write()` and `uart.read()` was now working correctly.

```
uart = serial.Serial('/dev/serial0', baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, timeout=1)
uart.write("Hello Serial!".encode())
```

Thanks again to Milliways for pointing that out.