# RPi 2 GPIO UART can send data to Teensy, but can't receive

Tags: pi-2, uart

I am trying to send data between `RPi 2 (model B)` and `Teensy 3.2` using the GPIO on the Pi (GPIO 14 and 15) and Serial2 on the Teensy (pins 9 and 10).

The problem is, I can only send data from the Pi to the Teensy, but not the other way round.

Python:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600, timeout=3)
print(ser.is_open)  # True
    
while True:
    data = ser.readline()
    print("Data: {}".format(data))
```

Teensy:

```
void setup() {
    Serial2.begin(9600);
    Serial2.setTimeout(500);
}

void loop() {
    Serial2.println("hello");
    delay(1);
}
```

The Python code always ends up in a timeout (reading empty data).

Things I've tried and didn't help:

Code:

- Changing the timeout, and without timeout
- Loop delay (to slow down read/write speed)
- Testing with read() and print() instead of readline() and println()

Pi:

- Restart (of course)
- Disable and re-enable the UART via raspi-config ("would you like the serial port hardware to be enabled")
- Disable "login shell over serial" (again raspi-config), I read somewhere it might help
- Using sudo

But nothing helped.

I also checked this: [UART Send/Receive not working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63468/uart-send-receive-not-working) but with no success.

• When "login shell over serial" is enabled, `sudo` is required in order to run the Python code (access the port). When it is disabled, it isn't required.

• When I check `ls -l /dev/* output, it says "*serial0 -> ttyAMA0`, and one line above `serial`. That's all it says about serial. (Not quite sure if that even helps)

• The file `/boot/config.txt` has `enable_uart=1`

I checked the wiring and everything seems to be fine, so I assume it has something to do with the Pi software.

I thought maybe the RX pin is already used by something else, but I couldn't find if, and how I can check it.

What else can I try? Is there something I am missing?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: " so I assume it has something to do with the Pi software" Why this is (unusual) Linux/python code not specific to Pi. Have you checked the Arduino code? Why don't you try some proper diagnostics to see what is actually happening?

Comment: @Milliways thanks for the comment. Well, I know that the codes aren't the problem because the Teensy UART works just fine when I connect it to another Teensy, (which means both the code and the board are fine) and the Python code works as well, when I connect it to a PC (and not Pi). That's how I isolated the problem. And therefore, I suspect there is something about the Pi.

Comment: PCs do not have GPIO.  You presumably used a different method of connection which is not relevant to the Pi.  `Show a photo of the Pi connections.`  Are the GPIO in the correct mode?  What does piscope show when you send/receive data?